# Validation of integer in fluent validation when character is not number

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have installed fluent validation in my web api core project. I created one validator in which I have validations for one field.

My TrainingDto.cs looks like this:

```
public class TrainingDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TrainingName { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfTrainings { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

My validator looks like this:

```
public class TrainingDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<TrainingDto>
{
    public TrainingDtoValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.NumberOfTrainings)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Number of trainings can't be empty.")
            .Must((x, list, context) =>
            {
                if (x.NumberOfTrainings.ToString() != "")
                {
                    context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("NumberOfTrainings", x.NumberOfTrainings);
                    return Int32.TryParse(x.NumberOfTrainings.ToString(), out int number);
                }
                return true;
            })
            .WithMessage("Number of trainings must be a number.");
    }
}
```

The problem is with this second validation condition. When I type letter instead of number, I got exception message "Could not convert string to integer: a. Path 'numberOfTrainings', line 1, position 24." instead of this message "Number of trainings must be a number." I want to show on the screen my validation message instead of this ASP.NET exception message. Number in this field should be greather than 0. Is this possible? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you calling `NumberOfTrainings.ToString()` when `x.NumberOfTrainings` is presumably already a `String`?

Comment: BTW, if you make `NumberOfTrainings` an `int` property then ASP.NET will do the validation for you already - is there a reason you're using a `string` (I assume it's a `string` - you haven't showed us your definition of `TrainingDto`).

Comment: @Dai, thank you for your comment, I will edit my question.

Comment: Hi,I could not reproduce the issue.I use asp.net core 2.2 and FluentValidation 8.3.0 and FluentValidation.AspNetCore 8.3.0.When i pass the NumberOfTrainings with string,it could not bind the string value to NumberOfTrainings and give the error message:`"The value '1k' is not valid for NumberOfTrainings.", "Number of trainings can't be empty."`.What is your version of asp.net core and FluentValidation?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit based on OP edit:**

As `NumberOfTrainings` is a nullable int, I would write the rule (using your messages) for ensuring this is not null and has a value greater than 0 as follows:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.NumberOfTrainings)
             .NotNull().WithMessage("Number of trainings can't be empty.")
             .GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Number of trainings must be greater than 0.");
```

A condensed set of tests for this rule would be as follows:

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();

var validator = new TrainingDtoValidator();

var dto1 = fixture.Build<TrainingDto>().Without(x => x.NumberOfTrainings).Create();
validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, dto1).WithErrorMessage("Number of trainings can't be empty.");

var dto2 = fixture.Build<TrainingDto>().With(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, -1).Create();
validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, dto2).WithErrorMessage("Number of trainings must be greater than 0.");

var dto3 = fixture.Build<TrainingDto>().With(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, 0).Create();
validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, dto3).WithErrorMessage("Number of trainings must be greater than 0.");

var dto4 = fixture.Build<TrainingDto>().With(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, 1).Create();
validator.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.NumberOfTrainings, dto4);
```

**Previous:**

`public int NumberOfTrainings { get; set; }` as per this definition cannot be null and it cannot be 'not a number'. So the custom property validator

```
.Must((x, list, context) =>
{
    if (x.NumberOfTrainings.ToString() != "")
    {
        context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("NumberOfTrainings", x.NumberOfTrainings);
        return Int32.TryParse(x.NumberOfTrainings.ToString(), out int number);
    }
    return true;
})
.WithMessage("Number of trainings must be a number.");
```

which is converting the `NumberOfTrainings` to a string, then attempting to parse it to an `Int32`, is redundant. I'm not even sure `NotEmpty` will work as you expect, as a default int is 0 which I wouldn't call empty. Maybe that checks for int.MinValue or something. Normally I'd write an int rule using a greater/less than or a range validator.

Can you elaborate on what is a 'valid NumberOfTrainings'? possibly >= 0? Then a better answer can be provided.

Comment: You are right, let say that this integer is nullable int (int?). And the numbers must be positive, greather than 0. I will edit my question again.

Comment: I have edited my comment with a rule for a nullable int that must not be null and must be a number greater than zero. If 0 is a valid number, use GreaterThanOrEqualTo instead.

Comment: This is working when I type number... but if I type letter, than I got the exception message, and validation is not working...

Comment: You'll have to include more code, what your view/form looks like, for us to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
LessThanOrEqualTo and GreaterThanOrEqualTo do not support but if you want, you can use like this way
RuleFor(I => I.Number).NotNull().WithMessage("your message")
.LessThanOrEqualTo(24).WithMessage("your message")
.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);

OR,
use new way InclusiveBetween

.InclusiveBetween(0, 24).WithMessage("your message");
```